# In Nginx, files without extensions to be PHP

Tags: php, nginx

I'm trying to convert the Apache directive `AddHandler` or `DefaultType` that allows me to set PHP to process files that do not have any extension at all. In Nginx, the closest that googling has suggested is this:

```
default_type application/x-httpd-php;
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. The file just downloads as plain text file. I've put this in the main http block as well as inside my server, in a specific location block:

```
    location / {
        default_type application/x-httpd-php;
        location ~.*\.(gif|jpg|png)$ {expires max;}
    ....etc.
```

Doesn't work. What can I do?

Comment: This is not a good idea and I cannot see why one would want to do this. Are you sure you are not just looking for a solution for "clean URLs", so something like `http://some.server/script?arg=one`?

Comment: (Shucks, comments don't have proper code formatting?) Yes, pretty URLs is pretty much the only reason. But we have a bunch of URLs which are just a word (without the .php extension behind), and a couple of key subfolders too.

    RewriteRule ^/folder/(.*)$ /folder/$1.php [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^/folder/otherfolder/(.*)$ /folder/otherfolder/$1.php [L,QSA]

I am trying this:

    location /folder {
      rewrite ^/folder/(.*)$ /folder/$1.php break;
    }

But not sure this is efficient?

Comment: If "clean URLs" are the sole purpose of this, then why don't you use rewriting rules in apache or the corresponding "try_files" statement in nginx to map such a URL to a php script? Modifications like what you attempt will raise many other issues in the long run.

Comment: We use only Nginx. No Apache with nginx proxy. So I need only Nginx rules. (Btw, I find if used only by itself, it's visibly faster.)

Comment: I, I understood that. I only refetred to apache to point out the similarity of both solutions. Most explanations assume you are using apache, but the idea is the same in the end. I really think you shoulg go with normal file name extensions for you php files.